# Retrieve the name of a Json property in logic apps

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

Hi i was wondering if there is a way to extract/retrieve/get the name of a property from a Json object in logic apps.

Whet i have is an XML embedded in a Json object (don't ask me why, please)

What i am doing is to convert/parse the content (the xml) inside the Json object, to Json. I want to be able to get the name of a specific property.

This is what i have for now:

```
json(xml(outputs('Compose')['xmlObject']))?['RootProperty']['SubProperty']
```

What i get is the content/data inside the property "SubProperty".
What i want to get as a result is the name/phrase "SubProperty", That is the name of it.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

So what i mean is that i want the name of the node i''m selecting in simple terms.

So in stead of getting a result of whats IN "SubProperty", That is:

[image]

i Want the name of the parent node so to speak. That is "SubProperty", as a result.

[image]

Comment: Hey, can you share how did you achieve this? If you add as answer here then it will be helpful to others like me :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the JSONPath spec(s) do not have a way to return metadata about a document, such as element names.

You'd have to work around this in some very circuitous way such as converting the JSON to Xml or a JavaScript to .parse() the JSON and treat it as an object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, och so there is another possibility then. Using Xpath i guess? 

{xpath(xml(outputs('Compose')['xmlObject']), '/RootNode/SubNode/[SYNTAX TO GET NAME]')}

Would this be possible?

Comment: @John Yes, after converting to Xml, you can try XPath with the name() or local-name() function.